# How to create app like iBooks

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to create app like iBooks?

I want to create app like iBooks. I want to know how i can curl the page of pdf.
Please share your ideas to create this app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this library](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/leaves),  might be a good starting point:

Comment: Thanks For the reply nice post i will try to do it today.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like render the page as a texture to a 3d surface that is initially flat, which you could then deform and animate to provide the curling animation.